# How to install pillow in docker.?

Tags: django, dockerfile, python-3.7

I'm trying to install **Pillow** in Docker but I get this error "*An error occurred while installing pillow==6.0.0*"

Anyone who has a clue on how to install Pillow in Docker even in if it is installing through **Dockerfile**?

Comment: tell us more, what base image are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The chances are that you need to install some pillow dependencies first:

```
RUN apk --update add \
    build-base \
    jpeg-dev \
    zlib-dev
```